# On the representation of composition of functions: how to pronounce $g\circ f$ when speaking?

Tags: functions, terminology, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$

Then one defines composition of functions as follows,
$$g(f(s)):X\rightarrow Z $$
For all $s\in X$. I also saw the following notation being used,
$$g \circ f:X\rightarrow Z$$
Now I was wondering how to say $g\circ f$ while speaking?

Can it be pronounced "$g$ circle $f$" or should it be pronounced as "$g$ compose $f$"?

I also think there are couple of mistakes in my understanding then i request to let me know.

Comment: $g(f(s))$ takes $X$ into $Z$

Comment: Thanks @311411, fixed it.

Comment: I like to pronounce $f\circ g$ as "f following g", but others pronounce in various ways.

Comment: I say "$g$ after $f$."

Comment: In french we say « g rond f » which litteraly means « g circle f » haha